# Talend TMAP - lookup returning ZERO and not actual results

Tags: etl, lookup, talend, tmap

I am trying to design a ETL to move data from a table called stage.pizzas and move it to a new table called landing.pizzas , while doing this the landing.pizzas table has an extra foreign key column called lfk_pizza_type_id which i have to look up in a third table column as landing.pizza_types (lpk_pizza_type_id) , now when i create this login in tmap, i only get zero out of the lookup table and not actual lpk_pizza_type_id below are images of source, target and lookup table, with lookup fields highlighted as yellow and output field in green and at the bottom is image of tmap logic.

**[stage].[pizzas]**

[image: Source- Stage Pizzas Table]

**[landing].[pizza_types]**

[image: Lookup Landing pizza_type table]

**[landing].[pizzas]**

[image: Target Table (landing Pizzas Table) Schema]

*Now below is the TMAP design (row2 is [stage].[pizzas] and row11 is [landing].[pizza_types] and insert is [landing].[pizzas])*

[image: tmap]

now, the fields mentioned are setup as INTEGER everywhere